# Akeneo keeps writing a dev.log

Tags: php, logging, production-environment, log-rotation, akeneo

I'm using Akeneo 2.1.8, but on my production server it keeps writing log entries to a `var/logs/dev.log`. These are simple INFO-entries and add +/- 100 MB every day to the log file.

How can I disable the `dev.log` on production? I cannot seem to find a logical entry in any of the configuration files or in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most likely running a command or a cron task with a command without the `-e=prod`. https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/console/usage.html

If it's not that are you using the app.php in your prod env ?
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/web_server_configuration.html

(Akeneo or  Symfony app should not write any dev log in prod. If there are dev log it mean something is running in dev mode. Likely a command or app_dev.php)

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed the missing of `--env=prod` in certain calls to CLI commands (in cron and bash scripts).